# Exporting an ESRI feature dataset (not a feature class) to a GeoPackage?

Tags: file-geodatabase, geopackage, feature-dataset

Is there a way to export an ESRI feature dataset (not a feature class) to a GeoPackage? Alternatively, is there a way to create a hierarchical vector data structure in a GeoPackage?

Finally, fearing that the answer in both instances is 'no', has anyone created a PostGIS schema that replicates a GDB schema? If yes, where can I learn about the steps?

Comment: Question is a little too broad and liable for closing for that reason

Comment: On the creating a hierarchy in a geopackage which is a sqlite database under the hood, yes it is possible.   How to do it in ArcGIS is a question.

Comment: I think that this is a very interesting and useful question, and it is not too broad. The Geopackage format is becoming more commonplace, and accordingly, the GIS community needs to become more knowledgeable with its capabilities.  This question is directly related to the Geopackage issue.

Comment: Could you describe the structure of your data? GeoPackage is made to support flat tables without relations but internally it is just a  SQLite database and it should be possible to mimic your schema. It may result a non-standard GeoPackage, though.

Comment: Have a convention of a geopackage (or a PostGIS schema) = a feature dataset?